# jquery form validation to prevent submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have been trying to use jquery to validate a form but i have been running into some issues.The link is below please take a look.

[Jiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jkozla01/z0pk7pk4/4/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-ca" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle3.css">
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/vendor/js/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/vendor/js/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#inputform" ).validate({
        rules: {
            fname: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 2,
                   maxlength: 20,
                   alphanumeric: true,
                },
            lname: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 2,
                   maxlength: 20,
                   alphanumeric: true,
            },
            street: { 
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 4,
                   street: true,

            },
            city: { 
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 4,

            },
            birthdate: { 
                   required: true,
                   date: true,

            },
            zip: { 
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 4,
                   maxlength: 5,
                   digits: true,
                   zip: true
            }, 
            tel: { 
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 10,
                   tele: true,


            },
            birthdate:{
                    required: true,
                    check_date_of_birth: true
            },
                 email: { 
                   required: true,
                   email: true

            },


        },
        messages: {

        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric",
        function(value, element) {
            return /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_ -]+$/.test(value);
        },
        "Sorry, no special characters allowed");
});
    $.validator.addMethod('zip', function (value) { 
        return /^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d))$/.test(value); 
    }, 'Please enter a valid US zip code.');

    $.validator.addMethod('street', function (value) { 
        return /^[a-zA-Z0-9-\/] ?([a-zA-Z0-9-\/]|[a-zA-Z0-9-\/] )*[a-zA-Z0-9-\/]$/.test(value); 
    }, 'Please enter a valid street address.');

    $.validator.addMethod('city', function (value) { 
        return /^[a-zA-z] ?([a-zA-z]|[a-zA-z] )*[a-zA-z]$/.test(value); 
    }, 'Please enter a valid City.');

    $.validator.addMethod('tele', function (value) { 
        return /^(([2-9]{1}[0-9]{2}) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/.test(value); 
    }, 'Please enter a valid Telephone number.');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
        yearRange: '1900:'+ curr_year,
        changeMonth:true,
        changeYear:true, maxDate: '-1d'
    });
});
</script>
<title>Assignment 3 Input form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.jkozla.com/default.htm"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Assignments</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment1.htm><span>Assignment 1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment2.htm><span>Assignment 2</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment3.html><span>Assignment 3</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment4.htm><span>Assignment 4</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment5.htm><span>Assignment 5</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment6.htm><span>Assignment 6</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment7.htm><span>Assignment 7</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment8.htm><span>Assignment 8</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment9.htm><span>Assignment 9</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment10.htm><span>Assignment 10</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href=http://www.jkozla.com/assignment/Assignment11.htm><span>Assignment 11</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class='active has-sub'><a href="#"><span>Classes</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href="https://cop4813eaglin.pbworks.com/w/page/34415594/FrontPage"><span>COP4813</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href="https://cas.fsu.edu/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fcampus.fsu.edu%2Fwebapps%2Fbb-auth-provider-cas-bb_bb60%2Fexecute%2FcasLogin%3Fcmd%3Dlogin%26authProviderId%3D_105_1%26redirectUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fcampus.fsu.edu%252Fwebapps%252Fportal%252Fframeset.jsp%26sessionIdForLogout%3DEB7D8A9EDEE7CA79B83CA34E8C9FA206"><span>MAD2104</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class='active has-sub'><a href="#"><span>Project</span></a>

    <li class='last'><a href="mailto:jmk13c@my.fsu.edu"><span>Contact</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<h1>COP 4813 Form Validation</h1>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="inputform" method="POST" onsubmit="submitHandler"  action="mailto:jmk13c@my.fsu.edu" enctype="text/plain"> 
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "6LcFzgwTAAAAAGl09TEBMh9akRJDZwuBDZEl0qHC"; // you got this from the signup page
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>

  <p>
    <label for="fname">First Name:&nbsp;</label>
    <input name="fname" class="fname" id="fname" type="text" name="fname" size="15" /><br><br>

    <label for="lname">Last Name:&nbsp;</label>
    <input name="lname" class="required" id="lname" type="text"  size="15" /><br><br>

    <label for="street">Street Address:&nbsp;</label>
    <input name="street" class="required" id="street" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" size="20" /><br><br>

    <label for="city">City:&nbsp;</label>
    <input name="city" class="required" id="city" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" size="15" /><br><br>

    <label for="state">State:&nbsp;</label>
        <select name="state" id="state" size="1"><br><br>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="DC">Dist of Columbia</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select><br><br>


    <label for="zip">Zipcode:&nbsp;</label>
    <input name="zip" class="required" id="zip" type="text" size="8" /><br><br>

    <label for="tel">Phone Number:&nbsp;</label>
    <input name="tel" class="required" id="tel" type="tel" data-mask="000 000-0000" placeholder="xxx xxx-xxxx" size="10" /><br><br>

    <label for="birthdate">DOB:&nbsp;</label>
    <input name="birthdate" type="text"  class="required" id="txtDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" size="15" /><br><br>

    <label for="email">Email:&nbsp;</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="required"  size="15" /><br><br>

    Message:<br>
    <textarea name="comment" required rows="4" cols="50"></textarea> <br><br>

    <div class="g-recaptcha"  data-sitekey="6LcFzgwTAAAAAGl09TEBMh9akRJDZwuBDZEl0qHC"></div>
</p>
<p><input name="send"  type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
<div id="fixedfooter">Copyright © Jonathan Kozla. All rights reserved.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. I can get it to validate to the point where it warns if conditions are not met but if all boxes are filled i can still submit even though it is wrong
2. When i use the recapcha, the site key gets included in the email when submitted.

Keep in mind this is homework that has been already submitted but for me to learn i need to know where i went wrong. Please help

Comment: while editing your code, i see you went wrong here `$(function() {` you closed it before the validation, check the edited post, you can see the closing brackets `});` you closed it before `$.validator.addMethod('zip', function (value) {`

Comment: Ok it validates like a champ but once i hit submit, i can still submit wrong data. What can i do to fix this?

Comment: this script `<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/vendor/js/additional-methods.js"></script>` included in head section 3 times should be one

Comment: ignore my last comment, i m just going through your code, but i don't see you created date of birth validation method `check_date_of_birth:`

Comment: I have to remove some garbage code, I ended up using date picker and that works well

Comment: can you provide the name of the inputs which are submitting wrong?

Comment: All of them except birthday, all of the field boxes warn about wrong inputs but I can still submit when all fields are filled

Comment: remove this `check_date_of_birth: true`

Comment: I'm leaving you can check this fiddle, it;s properly working https://jsfiddle.net/z0pk7pk4/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.preventDefault();` might help

Comment: where would i add that to?